# interface does not work for type const material ui BoxProps['sx']

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

interface does not work for type const material ui.
how to register an interface for sx here? I did this but it gives me an error

```
 import { BoxProps } from '@mui/material';
    
    interface Props {
    sx: BoxProps['sx'];
    }
    
    export const test: Props = {
    mb: 3,
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is defining that the object should have an `sx` property.

So in order to comply with the interface you can define the `test` like this:

```js
export const test: Props = {
  sx: { mb: 3 },
};
```

---

**OR** change the interface:

```js
type Props2 = BoxProps['sx']
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQgDwApQmAznAXzgDNsQ4ByAARAFdgB6EAQxgFMphmAbCgbgBQA4ADt2UYswDGbOFhz4EAuHFxoAXCnTy8AbQpqKAXUEEhAtmkiw4UiCNzx2jzTvwBeRMtUbEcEABGmgDMhAIEgkIwAJ5gsm4ATHCeqJjYegZoxkKW1vB2Dk5sjgmu6bhJnkoqgSEANOGCQA)

Comment: error BoxProps" refers only to the type, but is used here as a value